# What are the compactifications of those spirals?

Tags: general-topology

I want to find the **explicit compactification** (I don't mind if its a one-point compactification or not) of the spiral

$E_{1}=\left\{ \left(e^{t}\cos{t},e^{t}\sin{t}\right):t\in\mathbb{R}\right\} .$

and the spiral

$E_{2}=\left\{ \left(\frac{t}{t+1}\cos{t},\frac{t}{t+1}\sin{t}\right):t\in\left(0,+\infty\right)\right\}$

---

What I've managed to do is... for $E_{1}$:

First of all, I thought that I had to add $\left(0,0\right)$ because the limit when $t\rightarrow$-$\infty$ doesn't reach it, so the $\infty$ has to be linked to the origin, and because of the fact that $f\left(t\right)=\left(e^{t}\cos{t},e^{t}\sin{t}\right)$ is a parametrization, so it is an homeomorphism to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ so the compactification that comes to me is the one that comes with the map $f\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}
\left(e^{t}\cos{t},e^{t}\sin{t}\right) & t\in\mathbb{R}\\
\left(0,0\right) & t=-\infty
\end{cases}$ but $\partial E_{1}$ is what fails. So I don't think that I could the next one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One of the possible approaches I see is following. Your curve $E_2$ is homeomorphic to half-line $R_+$ or equivalently $[0,1)$ [see classification of 1-manifolds](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/1-manifolds#Reduction_to_classification_of_connected_manifolds). Now the one point compactification of $[0,1)$ is $[0,1]$. Thus $E_2$ can be compactified intto $[0,1]$. Don't know if this helps. You only need to find the above homeomorphism.

Comment: @ersh Thank you!! And for the other one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compactification of $E_2$ is $E_2 \cup S^1.$

Comment: +1... To the proposer:  Closed bounded subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ are compact so if $E$ is any bounded subset of $\Bbb R^2$ then $id_E:E\to \overline E$ is a compactification of $E.$  Also, BTW,$\; E_2$ is a locally compact Tychonoff space so it has a $1$-point compactification.